# Error al cargar fecha con un datepicker de angular material en formulario

Tags: angular7

En el html está:

```html
     <input
     matInput
     [matDatepicker]="to"
     formControlName="fecha"
     maxlength="10" >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="to"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #to></mat-datepicker>
```

```html
Esto esta en el ngOnInit
  this.form = this.fb.group({

      fecha: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required)
   
    });
```

He probado a **actualizar** con:

```
this.form.controls['fecha'].setValue({
  day: this.noticia.fecha.split("/")[0],
  month: this.noticia.fecha.split("/")[1],
  year: this.noticia.fecha.split("/")[2]
});
```

y con:

```
this.form.controls['fecha'].setValue(this.noticia.fecha);
```

y no funciona, ¿alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Funciona con el datepicker del formulario pero programaticamente no

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  date = new FormControl(new Date());
}
```

Comment: sigue sin actualizar, sale la fechA actual por defecto